# SQNR of 16 bit signed multiplication with MSB storing in 16 bits

Tags: dsp, math

I'm trying to figure out what the SQNR is if I multiply 2 16-bit signed integer values and store the result as a 16-bit signed integer, dropping the least significant bits.

For example:

a (16 bit signed) * b (16 bit signed) = c (16 bit signed) without the LSBs

And to be more clear about what's after this, I am summing many successive values of the resulting 'c' - this sum is stored in an infinite length signed integer representation.

How do I calculate the SQNR in this situation?

Comment: You should add more context for this question. For example, assuming SQNR means "signal to quantization noise ratio" (you really should spell these things out to avoid confusion), what do you consider the "signal" to be?

Comment: @DaveTweed that's correct on SQNR, the signal and noise are part of my confusion. Signal being the full 32 bit resolution that comes out as 'c' if we don't drop any bits, the noise being the noise introduced from those bits being dropped. I believe

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Remember to drop 15 LSBs, not 16.
Signed multiplication is a little odd, numerically, in that you are multiplying  2 15-bit numbers and 2 sign bits, giving a 30-bit number and 2 almost-redundant sign bits.

Almost redundant because the only occasion on which they will carry different information is -2**15 * -2**15 whose product is 2**30. If you can discount -2**15 on either input (e.g. because you know your filter coefficients) you can call the sign bits completely redundant. Failing that, take the MSB as the reliable one.

Apart from that, the SQNR will be no different from a truncation at the same word length which is a standard result, amenable to improvement by the usual techniques of dithered rounding or noise shaping.

Or keeping more (or all) of the product. Truncate or dither the accumulator output, not its inputs...